# Wordpress and IIS. Deploy two servers at one domain

Tags: php, .net, iis, domain

I want to add a wordpress blod on my site running on IIS. How can I do so?

e.g My blog URL will be www.mydomain.com/blog

I want to add a wordpress blod on my site running on IIS. How can I do so?

e.g My blog URL will be www.mydomain.com/blog

I tried to install PHP server(wamp), but it did not run due to port conflict. After changing port my url becomes e.g:

**www.mydomain.com**

**www.mydomain.com:1005/blog**

I want to run both my site and blog on same domain without any port in the URL. How can I overcome this port conflict.